# How do I align multiple formulas and their captions to the left?

Tags: floats, alignment

I'm sorry but not sure how to "trigger" my TeX code here (i.e., to generate output).

I have an appendix in which I want to include four formulas. As of now, they're centered, which looks odd IMO. I tried putting them to the left using a minipage, using a package (`\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}`) but it either doesn't put them to the left, or puts just formulas and not captions, or there's a different issue.

I also tried `\flushleft` or `\noindent` to no avail. I want them ideally to be aligned the same like the section.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Formulas for Performance Metrics}\label{app:perfmetrics}

\begin{figure}[H]
\[ A = \frac{TP + TN}{TP + TN + FP + FN}\]
\caption{Accuracy}\label{formula:accuracy}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\[ P = \frac{TP}{TP + FP}\]
\caption{Precision}\label{formula:precision}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\[ R =  \frac{TP}{TP + FN}\]
\caption{Recall}\label{formula:recall}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\[ F1 = 2 \times \frac{P \times R}{P + R}\]
\caption{F1-score}\label{formula:f1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This is how it looks now:

[image]

Comment: Why are you doing formulas as figures to begin with. Normally one leaves these as displayed formulas and number them

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In the following code, to left-align the caption I have used the `captionsetup` from the `caption` package. To place the equation on the left, the equation `IEEEeqnarray` environment from the [`IEEEtrantools`](https://ctan.org/pkg/ieeetrantools) package has been used. The `*` glue type does the trick.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false}
\usepackage{showframe} %just to show page layout

\begin{document}
\section{Formulas for Performance Metrics}\label{app:perfmetrics}

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{*l}
A = \frac{TP + TN}{TP + TN + FP + FN}
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}
% \[ A = \frac{TP + TN}{TP + TN + FP + FN}\]
\caption{Accuracy}\label{formula:accuracy}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{*l}
P = \frac{TP}{TP + FP}
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}
% \[ P = \frac{TP}{TP + FP}\]
\caption{Precision}\label{formula:precision}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{*l}
R =  \frac{TP}{TP + FN}
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}
% \[ R =  \frac{TP}{TP + FN}\]
\caption{Recall}\label{formula:recall}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{*l}
F1 = 2 \times \frac{P \times R}{P + R}
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}
% \[ F1 = 2 \times \frac{P \times R}{P + R}\]
\caption{F1-score}\label{formula:f1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**

Note: As mentioned in the comment and other answers, equations should not be inserted as figures in standard documents.

Comment: It is answers like this one what leads to the abuses denounced in [Horrors in LaTeX](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb26-3/tb84gregorio.pdf).

Comment: @jarnosz Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 3):

For one time use try this code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\section{Formulas for Performance Metrics}\label{app:perfmetrics}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
    $A = \frac{TP + TN}{TP + TN + FP + FN}$&
    Accuracy \label{formula:accuracy}\\
    &\\
    $P = \frac{TP}{TP + FP}$&
    Precision \label{formula:precision}\\
    &\\
    $R =  \frac{TP}{TP + FN}$&
    Recall\label{formula:recall}\\
    &\\
    $F1 = 2 \times \frac{P \times R}{P + R}$&
    F1-score \label{formula:f1}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Alternatevely you cas use this code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\section{Formulas for Performance Metrics}\label{app:perfmetrics}
\begin{tabular}{l}
    $A = \frac{TP + TN}{TP + TN + FP + FN}$\\
    Accuracy \label{formula:accuracy}\\
    \\
    $P = \frac{TP}{TP + FP}$\\
    Precision \label{formula:precision}\\
    \\
    $R =  \frac{TP}{TP + FN}$\\
    Recall\label{formula:recall}\\
    \\
    $F1 = 2 \times \frac{P \times R}{P + R}$\\
    F1-score \label{formula:f1}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Equations are not figures!

For referencing of equation they can have numbers or some other unique tag. To them also can be add description, for example as shown in the first example of @Raffaele Santoro answer (+1).

Let me further elaborate this idea. Using `nccmath` and `tabularx` package, this equation can be present also as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}
\section{Formulas for Performance Metrics}
\label{app:perfmetrics}

    \begin{center}
\abovedisplayskip=-2pt
\belowdisplayskip=-2pt
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} r<{:} >{\fleqn}X<{\endfleqn} @{}}
Accuracy    &   \begin{gather}\label{formula:accuracy}
                A = \frac{TP + TN}{TP + TN + FP + FN}
                \end{gather}      \\
Precision   &   \begin{equation}\label{formula:precision}
                P = \frac{TP}{TP + FP}
                \end{equation}      \\
Recall      &   \begin{equation}\label{formula:recall}
                R =  \frac{TP}{TP + FN}
                \end{equation}      \\
F1-score    &   \begin{equation}\label{formula:f1}
                F1 = 2 \times \frac{P \times R}{P + R}
                \end{equation}      \\
\end{tabularx}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]